# how do i use my own MIB file with net-snmp agent

Tags: agent, net-snmp, mib

I have written a MIB file which has just one OIDs (read-write) like .1.3...enterprises...Flag1.0

I have also installed net-snmp on my linux box. How can i get my mib file working with agent. I have got some idea of net-snmp, but i want to know what would be the best, easiest and reliable way to getting this done ->

There will be a snmp-master who will be setting the flag and there will be internal scripts which can read the flag and perform certain actions based on the status of flag.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are adding a custom MIB to the standard tree. In this case, you need the new custom MIB and you also need to extend the standard SNMP agents functionality to support it.

There are a bunch of ways to extend the agent. This [article](http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2012-extending-netsnmp.html) covers a number of options.

Take a look at the Net-SNMP website tutorials. For example, try [Writing a MIB Module](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Writing_a_MIB_Module).